# Problem when logging in to multiple accounts when using flutter in_app_purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am implementing a payment module using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) in Flutter.

I have two problems.

1. It doesn't load products if I have more than one account on Google Play Store.
   The exact situation is as follows:
   That is, two accounts are registered in the Play Store, and only the second account in the sort order is logged in.
   In this case, no product is received when executing the `InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails({a, b, c})` function.
   (If I log in with one account, the product list is loaded correctly.)
2. Unknown error
   I registered two subscription products and one product.
   When I register or delete a product in the App Store or Play Store,
   When running InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails({a, b, c}), some of the requested products are missing.
   However, if I request it as follows, it will receive all the products.

```
(await Future.wait([
   _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails({a, b}),
   _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails({c})
]))
```

I don't know what I missed.

I'd like some help with some of this.

Thank you.